# IP error: Django app not deploying with docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I am new to Docker so I'm probably missing something obvious but here goes.  I am trying to test a simple Django app with docker postgres.  All I want right now is to verify that the home page is working on localhost.  Debug output window gives me the following:

```
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | April 28, 2020 - 17:06:23
web_1  | Django version 3.0.5, using settings 'app.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

However when I go to 0.0.0.0:8000 I get an error that says the site can't be reached

```
"The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

**Here is my docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
```

**Here is my dockerfile:**

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.8

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . /app/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Would greatly appreciate any insight or help with troubleshooting.  Because there are no errors in the debug window I'm not really sure where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `http://localhost:8000/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Comment: Tried both, still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Solved it by using [Iain Shelvington's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61485989/ip-error-django-app-not-deploying-with-docker/70026516#comment108767750_61485989):

> Try `http://localhost:8000/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Apparently `0.0.0.0` in the Dockerfile maps to `localhost` in the browser.